# Side by side <td> elements to have the same height

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm a little bit stuck on something CSS related. I have a table that has two td elements and in each td element is a table with a fieldset.

I am hoping to get each fieldset in each td to have the same height.

When I run it though I see that each fieldset is a different height depending on the data inside each table. I can see that each td is the same height which I expected although 100% height still does not seem to work.

[image]

```css
p,
table,
fieldset {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
p {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro";
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
table td {
  background-color: #333333;
}
table td td {
  background-color: #666666;
  height: 100%;
}
fieldset {
  border: solid 1px #fcff00;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
fieldset table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <!-- LEFT HAND SIDE -->
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 01</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 02</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 03</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <!-- RIGHT HAND SIDE -->
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 04</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables for layouts in 2016?

Comment: There's a time and place for tables, this is one of those times

Comment: The time and place is when displaying tabular data, and if you have tables within tables, it's probably a sign you're not using it correctly (unless you are showing grouped data)

Comment: This is example code, the real result is to hold input fields and their descriptions in a tabular format.

Comment: If you don't have to support old browsers, flexbox is the only way to do it without JS. See http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Have you tried putting the border in the <td>, instead of the fieldset?

Comment: I tried putting the border on the td which worked except that I can't use the legend with the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the position tricks + pseudo element to do it without any markup changes.

```
table, fieldset, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
p {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro";
  color: #fff;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  padding: 8px;
}
table td:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px; right: 4px; top: 4px; bottom: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #fcff00;
}
table table td {
  background: #666;
  padding: 0;
}
table table td:after {
  display: none;
}
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go0vne65/)**

```css
table, fieldset, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
p {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro";
  color: #fff;
}
table td {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  padding: 8px;
}
table td:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px; right: 4px; top: 4px; bottom: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #fcff00;
}
table table td {
  background: #666;
  padding: 0;
}
table table td:after {
  display: none;
}
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <!-- LEFT HAND SIDE -->
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 01</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 02</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 03</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <!-- RIGHT HAND SIDE -->
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Line 04</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use the CSS3 [**flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) instead of table layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q25ufvr7/)**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.container .item {
  outline: 4px solid #333; /*outer*/
  border: solid 1px #fcff00; /*inner*/
  background: #333;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container .item p {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
}
.container .item p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Line 01</p>
    <p>Line 02</p>
    <p>Line 03</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Line 04</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change from `height: 100%` to `height: inherit;`. Percentage works only when the parent's height is declared.

Answer (score 0):

RIGHT HAND SIDE

```
<td rowspan="3">
```

I think that can make it
I already haved that problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also put min-height with CSS. So it will be responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found an incredibly simple result without needing Flex Box or JavaScript.

All I had to do was put height="1" on the necessary td elements and the 100% height worked.

```
<td valign="top" height="1"><!-- LEFT HAND SIDE -->
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</td>

<td valign="top" height="1"><!-- RIGHT HAND SIDE -->
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/katpmLe8/

I don't know why it works but it feels simpler than learning a new technology that I don't understand

Comment: It seems all items are stretched, and it's a mess on Firefox.

Comment: It will probably look crap for a while but I didn't spend any time making it pretty, besides it's running on the node-webkit built in browser engine and it looks fine there

Comment: OK, I've just found a better way to do it with your existing markup, updated the answer, hope it helps.